# If Binding Property is Null, then bind with simple message in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Sorry for confusing title, feel free to change it.

Lets say I have a textblock which binds to `SomeProperty`. 
This `SomeProperty` is going to be `null` at some point and if that `SomeProperty` is `null`, then I want to create A simple Label saying that This property doesnt have value or some other simple messages.

This is my sample textblock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I want to create Label which contains simple message in its content if `SomeProperty` is `null`.

Is it possible to achieve only using `XAML` ?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. While `OneWay` is the default Mode for the Text property anyway, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in a OnewWay Binding. It only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [`TargetNullValue` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the `Binding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, TargetNullValue=This is the message}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the Label to monitor for changes on the property, when the property is null it will change the value of the Label for you. For example,

```
    <Label >
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Default Value" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="The value is null!" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```